# jQuery div Hide and show other div 5 seconds setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have div box , in this box is to  div.  first div - is load first  , after 5 seconds load second div.

```
<div style=" width: 500px; height:500px;">

<div id="first-box">Waite 5 seconds </div>
<div id="second-box"> Hi All </div>

</div>
```

i need  jQuery setTimeout function for this

Comment: you have anything so far?

Comment: this  <div id="second-box"> Hi All </div>  did not hide otter 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're going to add a whole lot more information about what's being added.  To add a 5 second delay to an element here's the code:

You need to first hide the element with this css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

And this addition to your html:

```
<div id="second-box" class="hide">Hi All</div>
```

This is the jQuery.  On document load, it will wait 5 seconds then remove the hide class from the #second-box element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#second-box').removeClass('hide');
    }, 5000);
});
```

**The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qx7ebyn2/**

Comment: Perhaps the answer could be improved to also cover the difference between jQuery, ECMA script and [W3C DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout); `setTimeout` belongs to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code as reference and make change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".first, .second, .third").hide();
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.first').show();
    }, 1000);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.second').show();
    }, 2000);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.third').show();
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>

<div class="main ">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="second"> second </div>
    <div class="third"> third </div>
</div>
```

> There is theree DIV class (first,second and third), it's shown one by one by
>   setTimeout Interval.